# Passing spinner value string to second activity

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to convert the selection from a spinner to a string in one activity, then pass this string into another activity and convert it to an integer, when an enter button is pressed. Problem is that after I select from the spinner, the emulator keeps crashing after I hit enter.

Activity 1 with spinner choice and enter button::

```
        btnSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog d2 = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            d2.setContentView(R.layout.inputalarmnum);                                              
            Button btnEnterNum = (Button) d2.findViewById(R.id.btnEnterNum);                
            final Spinner numberAlarmChoice = (Spinner) d2.findViewById(R.id.spinnerAlarmNum);

            btnEnterNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String selection = numberAlarmChoice.getSelectedItem().toString();                      
                    Intent alarmSet = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmActivity.class);
                    alarmSet.putExtra(selection,"sel");
                    startActivity(alarmSet);
                }
            });
            d2.show();
        }
    });
```

And then retrieving the string in another activity(this is from the oncreate method):

```
Intent getSel = getIntent();
String selection = getSel.getExtras().getString("sel");
final Integer alarmNumInt = Integer.valueOf(selection);
```

Any suggestions of why the app keeps crashing, is there a logical error?

Comment: can you please add the errormessage (LogCat) details from the crash.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the extra wrong. It's `(key, value)`, you're doing `(value, key)`:

```
alarmSet.putExtra(selection,"sel"); //wrong
```

Try

```
alarmSet.putExtra("sel", selection); //correct
```

Also, you don't need to convert to a String, you can have an extra with an Integer value.

Comment: Thanks alot mate. Guess i missed that one. Works as it should now.

Comment: No problem! Things like these are always easier to spot when you haven't been staring at them for hours :)